# Login to prestashop 1.7 through webservices

Tags: web-services, authentication, ionic4, prestashop-1.7, password-encryption

Prestashop noob here. I am creating an ionic app with prestashop 1.7.

---

TL;DR:

I can't use the same encryption as Prestashop 1.7 to compare app user password with the encrypted one from the DB

---

Details:

So prestashop does not provide a proper way to log in(Login word is not even mentioned in documentation).
I am thinking of getting the customer with the entered email(api/customers/?filter[email]=INPUT_EMAIL), then encrypting the INPUT_PASSWORD encrypted with the "passwd" attribute from the api.
The problem is I am not able to apply the same encryption as done by Prestashop(they will never match even if the password is correct)

PS:

I tried `md5(COOKIE_KEY+INPUT_PASSWORD)` but still not the right thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late, but I am sure other people will face this.
What I did was same procedure mentioned in the question: get the customer info and match passwords.
Prestashop 1.6 apparently used md5 but PS 1.7 uses bcrypt, so you have to:

Get the bcryptjs package(I am using angular, there is bcrypt package for nodejs).

Change replace `$2y$` by `$2a$` (the first one used by PHP's bcrypt the second by Javascript's).

Compare the hash against the typed password `bcrypt.compare(INPUT_PASSWORD, pwd)`

From there if they match then you adapt your app to behave as wanted.